# Passing an object to a function gets error

Tags: c++

I am trying to pass an object to a function.
I got two errors from the function declaration in car.h
I am using vs2019, VC++.

```
overloaded function "Car::Car" is not a type name
syntax error: identifier '{ctor}' <<<<< about the object named car
```

Engine class

```
class Engine {
    protected:
        // some variables

    public:
        // default constructor and destructor
        // some function
};
```

SUV class

```
class SUV : public Engine {
    protected:
        // some variables

    public:
        // default constructor and deconstructor
        // some function
};
```

Car class

```
class Car : public SUV {
    public:
        Car();
        ~Car();
};
```

Factory class

```
class Factory {
    public:
        void MakeCar( int x, Car::Car car ); <<<<<< Errors
```

I really don't know why it doesn't work. Please tell me.
Thank you.

Comment: Inside `Car` class, you just say `Car`, not `Car::Car`.

Comment: After you fix that you have `void MakeCar( int x, Car car );` Are you sure you want to pass by value for that? Also not sure what the purpose of this function is. Does it make a copy, so a copy constructor would be more appropriate. But then what is the `x` parameter?

Comment: Just a minor point that might help next time you talk about C++ with other fellow programmers: "deconstructor" is not part of the language -- it's called the _destructor_. :)

Comment: My mistake. I am missing one class. I am changing my question. Sorry about that.

Comment: drescherjm, That is not the actual code, I try to convert it as close as I can to something that I can post publicly.

Comment: I did try void MakeCar( int x, Car car);. I got syntax error: identifier 'Car'

Comment: That means you are missing an include. Probably #include "car.h"

Comment: I did include header file.

Comment: Make sure car.h does not include factory.h. Having a circular header loop is often a cause of that.

Comment: This is the inherent problem when beginners try to create simplified examples.  Often it ends up in a nonsense question, or just the wrong question.

Comment: Thank, drescherjm, I think that probably the issue. One of the base class include Factory.

Comment: @paddy I still prefer that to users not even trying to make a minimal example, and posting 100 lines of code.

Comment: Thank you everyone. It is fixed. The reason of causing this error is the base class includes Factory in the header.

Comment: @cigien I wish I could. Unfortunately I am working on close source project. I can't post it.

Comment: @paddy destructor, changed on the question. Thanks.

Comment: No, my comment was not suggesting that you post all your code :) Quite the opposite in fact. You did the right thing by trying to make a simplified minimal example.

Comment: @drescherjm, thank you very much.

Comment: In C++ you'll often see factory functions return an allocated pointer to the base type if you're looking to use inheritance. Like `Engine* MakeCar(int x)` where that figures out what to do and returns the appropriate thing.